# how can I continue loop if find element fail?

Tags: selenium, webdriver

I 've tried 
is there any way that if the driver can't find the element, will not go to 'catch' but continue the while loop??

the code like this:

```
try{
     while (...) {
      driver.findelement(A);

   }
}catch(Exception e) {

}
```

Comment: I mean I want to continue the loop even the find fail

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
while (condition) {

      try{     

        driver.findElement(A);
      }
      catch(Exception e) {

      }
}
```

You have to do the try catch inside the loop

Comment: thanks a lot!  another question, do you know the return value of "driver.findelement(A);" ? I don't want to handle the error on catch, I want to handle it on ： if(driver.findelement(A) not found) {.....}, can I??

Comment: You should post this as a separate question.

Answer (score 1):

You can put the findelement part in the try-catch block

```
while (some_condition) {

    try {     
        driver.findElement(A);
    }
    catch(Throwable e) {
        /* Do something or ignore */
    }
}
```